# Get data-attribute value and HTML in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following tag in my html and I need to select the data-id value and the inner html value into an array.

How can I achieve this in either Jquery or Javascript

```
<li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="1">Politieacademie</li>
<li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="3">IBM</li>
<li class="dual-listbox__item dual-listbox__item--selected" data-id="5">Energias de Portugal</li>
```

Comment: You can use .map for something like this - add an example to the question of what you want the array to look like when its done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$('.dual-listbox__item').each()` to achieve this:

```js
var dataId = [];
var nHTML = [];
$('.dual-listbox__item').each(function(){
  dataId.push($(this).data('id'));
  nHTML.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(dataId);
console.log(nHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="1">Politieacademie</li>
<li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="3">IBM</li>
<li class="dual-listbox__item dual-listbox__item--selected" data-id="5">Energias de Portugal</li>
```

Comment: Also need the inner HTML value in array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) along with `.get()` to convert it to basic array

```js
var arr = $('li.dual-listbox__item').map(function() {
  return {
    id: $(this).data('id'),
    text: $(this).html()
  };
}).get();

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="1">Politieacademie</li>
  <li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="3">IBM</li>
  <li class="dual-listbox__item dual-listbox__item--selected" data-id="5">Energias de Portugal</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually I have another level higher up.   Can you please suggest how to retreive the data-id and the value from this.  <ul class="dual-listbox__selected"><li class="dual-listbox__item dual-listbox__item--selected" data-id="1">Politieacademie</li></ul>  I cannot rely on dual-listbox__item as it is selecting other entities from the DOM. I need to get all items from "dual-listbox__selected"

Comment: Use correct selector `var arr = $('ul.dual-listbox__selected li.dual-listbox__item.dual-listbox__item--selected').map(function() {
  return {
    id: $(this).data('id'),
    text: $(this).html()
  };
}).get();`

Answer (score 3):

Select the elements, loop them using map and you got your array. Below will return an array of objects holding the data you want

```js
const res = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dual-listbox__item')).map(e => ({
  dataId: e.dataset.id,
  innerHTML: e.innerHTML
}));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="1">Politieacademie</li>
<li class="dual-listbox__item" data-id="3">IBM</li>
<li class="dual-listbox__item dual-listbox__item--selected" data-id="5">Energias de Portugal</li>
```

Comment: eww `.getAttribute(...)`.

Comment: What else would you use @KarelG -- ah I see, `dataset`... Yeah, would be possible..

Comment: using `.dataset` is more cleaner. That `.getAttribute()` is an old thing and not reliable (different behavior throughout multiple spec versions). Moreover, a best practice is to use `hasAttribute()` beforehand. You missed an upvote here :P

Comment: Not for an upvote, but you're right :-) @KarelG I was to state that it's supported in IE10 and below, but the rest of my code isn't as well... :-)